# Getting error while importing a file: OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, importerror, oserror

I get following error message while trying to import a thisImagingSource file into my application. My current operating system is Windows10. Previously while using Windows8 I didn´t get this same error. Can some one help me?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b6bb7e0c0dc0> in <module>
      8 """
      9 import ctypes as C
---> 10 import tisgrabber as IC
     11 import cv2
     12 import numpy as np

~\Documents\Python Scripts_20200422\application\tisgrabber.py in <module>
     25 GrabberHandle._fields_ = [('unused', C.c_int)]
     26 
---> 27 class TIS_GrabberDLL(object):
     28     if sys.maxsize > 2**32 :
     29         __tisgrabber = C.windll.LoadLibrary("tisgrabber_x64.dll")

~\Documents\Python Scripts_20200422\application\tisgrabber.py in TIS_GrabberDLL()
     27 class TIS_GrabberDLL(object):
     28     if sys.maxsize > 2**32 :
---> 29         __tisgrabber = C.windll.LoadLibrary("tisgrabber_x64.dll")
     30     else:
     31         __tisgrabber = C.windll.LoadLibrary("tisgrabber.dll")

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in LoadLibrary(self, name)
    440 
    441     def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 442         return self._dlltype(name)
    443 
    444 cdll = LibraryLoader(CDLL)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle,     use_errno, use_last_error)
    362 
    363         if handle is None:
--> 364             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    365         else:
    366             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tisgrabber isn't included in the standard python libary so you have to install it. You could do this with the console command `pip install <name of the module>`.

Comment: Actually I have downloaded the module. It is a .py file and now I am trying to import it via "import tisgrabber". There is non need to pip install it, since it is already available on the drive. The problem occurs later in ctypes, where the error is thrown OSError :  [WinError 126]

Comment: I think they have the same problem